# How can I hide the SiteMapPath root node on home page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, sitemap

How can I hide the root node in a SiteMapPath control when the user is on the root node page? For example, my breadcrumb trail on a child page is:

> Home > Products > Hammers > Ball Peen

which is fine. But when the user is on the Home page, the SiteMapPath control displays

> Home

which is useless clutter. I want to suppress displaying Home (the root node) when the user is on the home page. I have the SiteMapPath control in a master page. Also, I'm handling SiteMapResolve to set the querystrings in the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out but it took a while because the problem I was having was somewhat subtle. schou-rode has the right idea and that is what I was doing in `Page_Load` without success. The reason it wasn't working is because I was cloning the node in `SiteMapResolve` and returning the clone. This occurred before `Page_Load` so `SiteMap.CurrentNode` referenced the clone and the comparison to `SiteMap.RootNode` failed.

Here's the full solution:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapPath1.Visible = (SiteMap.CurrentNode != SiteMap.RootNode);
}

private SiteMapNode SiteMap_SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    if (SiteMap.CurrentNode == null || SiteMap.CurrentNode == SiteMap.RootNode)
    {
        return SiteMap.CurrentNode;
    }
    // clone and set querystring in other nodes...
}
```

Comment: So, I answered your question correctly, you fixed something else and accepted your own answer? ;)

Comment: Not really -- I was already doing that but it didn't work because I was injecting a querystring into the path. Accepting my own answer is perfectly OK, there's even a "Self-Learner" badge for it, although this doesn't qualify (yet). I do appreciate your answer and I did upvote it.

Answer (score 13):

One possible solution would be to simply hide the `SiteMapPath` control on the home page:

```
mySiteMapPath.Visible = (SiteMap.CurrentNode != SiteMap.RootNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen some code-based examples, but here's a cheep CSS solution (your target browsers must support css 2.1 though) that will hide the root node and the following path-separator.

Kill the Root node by setting the RootNodeTemplate to empty like so:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" CssClass="breadCrumbTrail">
   <RootNodeTemplate></RootNodeTemplate>
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

That will make it render nothing for the Root node, but the Root's path-separator will still be displayed, so add these CSS selectors to your stylesheet (Important: notice I gave my SiteMapPath1 element a CssClass named 'breadCrumbTrail'):

```
.breadCrumbTrail
{
  font-size: small;
}

/*
First child element rendered by a SiteMapPath is an <a> tag you have no control over, 
adjacent to that is your root node's span tag, adjacent to that is the root node's 
path-separator span: don't display it.
*/
.breadCrumbTrail > a:first-child + span + span
{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The one of the right way to hide SiteMapPath root note in 3 easy steps:**

- Reference MasterPage from ContentPage

  **Example:**

  ```
  <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master.master" %>
  ```
- Make SiteMapPath as Protected Internal in designer class

  **Example:**

  ```
  protected internal global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapPath SiteMapPath1;
  ```
- Hide it from ContentPage

  **Example:**

  ```
  Master.SiteMapPath1.Visible = (SiteMap.CurrentNode != SiteMap.RootNode);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

On the home page, add the script below to the "head" part:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapPath sp = (SiteMapPath)Master.FindControl("SiteMapPath1");
    sp.Visible = (SiteMap.CurrentNode != SiteMap.RootNode);
}
```

To apply the above method, `SiteMapPath1` should be placed on the MasterPage.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a ShowStartingNode property on the SiteMapDataSource. Set this to false to hide the root node.

Comment: Why did it take me so long time to find this obvious, and obviously  best answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had mine plugged into my _Layout.cshtml and found the easiest solution was to wrap an If statement (with previously suggested logic) around the control rendering block and call it a day:

```
@if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != SiteMap.RootNode)
{
  @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="contentNavigation" runat="server">
    <RootNodeTemplate>
    </RootNodeTemplate>
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

and css code :

```
#ctl00_contentNavigation span:nth-child(2),span:nth-child(3)
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had similar problem, but I am using XmlDataSource for the menu in my solution .

Sample structure of the source XML:

```
<root>
  <Menu text="" url=""/>
  <Menu text="" url=""/>
</root>
```

If you want to NOT display 'root' menu item, you have to simple set XPath property on the XmlDataSource to value '/root/*'

Answer (score 0):

**ParentLevelsDisplayed=0** will help

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" PathSeparator="" 
        ParentLevelsDisplayed="0" >
        <RootNodeTemplate></RootNodeTemplate>            
    </asp:SiteMapPath>
```